GTM is disconnected on every page change on NextJS
In my layout.js, I have the GoogleTagManager :
<GoogleTagManager gtmId="GTM-XXXXXX" />

In my folder "pages", i have a lot of routes :

Each page generates a new GTM ID.
I tried to use the script instead of the module GTM, but it doesn't change anything.
Can someone help me?
